# iup webbrowser loading local file via hyperlink

Tags: html, lua, iup

When referencing an http url through webbrowser it works correctly. but loading a local file seems something wrong with webbrowser. NB IE doesn't require "file:///".  I have tested it in IE it works. but not in iup embedded IE webbrowser.
The code is shown below:

```
require('iuplua')
require('iupluaweb')

local MyWeb = iup.webbrowser{}

function MyWeb:navigate_cb(url)
      iup.Message('', url)
      return iup.IGNORE
end

MyWeb.HTML = [[
<HTML>
<BODY>
<A HREF="D://Folder1//Folder2//test.htm";>LocalHtmlPage</A>
<A HREF="http://www.google.com";>Google.com</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
]]

local MainForm = iup.dialog{
      title = 'Hyperlinking',
      size = 'HALFxHALF',
      MyWeb,
    }

MainForm:show()
iup.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Actually I tested several forms. For instance:

<A HREF="file:///D:/tecgraf/iup/html/en/ctrl/iupweb.html";>LocalHtmlPage1</A>
<A HREF="D:/tecgraf/iup/html/en/ctrl/iupweb.html";>LocalHtmlPage2</A>
<A HREF="D:\\tecgraf\\iup\\html\\en\\ctrl\\iupweb.html";>LocalHtmlPage3</A>
None of them work.

Comment: This works:
MyWeb.value = "file:///D:/tecgraf/iup/html/en/ctrl/iupweb.html"

Comment: So I guess it could be something related to security because the ERROR_CB callback is not even triggered in the code (NavigateError method of the IE interface).

Comment: Thanks Scuri. But How do I cater it, any workaround using javascript/jquery etc. I also checked IE embedding using RapidQ, It also gave same errors.

Comment: Linking external js file via "<script src="myscripts.js"></script>" also does not work.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe in the Internet Options at the Control Panel.